# React Hooks change single value of object with multiple keys without repetition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find a neater way to handle this pattern I keep coming across with react when handling changes for form fields.

For each element of my form object that I handle a change in value for I find myself replicating this pattern quite a bit with the setter function of useState(). I've tried a couple of things like creating shallow copies of the formState and mutating that but the only way I can really get things to work is with the bellow pattern which feels a little repetitive.

```
 const handleTitle = evt => {
    props.setFormState({
      title: evt.target.value,
      bio: props.formState.bio,
      formExpertise: props.formState.formExpertise,
      formExpertiseYears: props.formState.formExpertiseYears
    });
  };
```

Comment: I don't know what your setFormState function looks like, but with traditional state you only have to send the properties that change. If you do have to specify them all, you can at least make it more concise by breaking apart the previous object, `props.setFormState({ ...props.formState, title: evt.target.value }); This puts all the previous properties there on the same level, including title, which is then overwritten by the title you set explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for asking a "best practices" style of specific question. I find many that bring up illuminating answers, such as [@ray hatfield's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636077/ray-hatfield), below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include `this.props.formState` you can spread the object into the new state. Further, you can use the input’s name as the state key so you don’t have to rewrite this for every input:

```js
props.setFormState({
  ...this.props.formState, // copy props.formState in
  [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value // use input name as state key
});
```

---

### Suggestion:

You might consider moving the state merging up into the parent component:

```
// parent component
const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({});

const onFieldChange = (field, value) => {
  setFormState({
    ...formState,
    [field]: value
  });
}

return (
  <MyFormComponent
    formState={formState}
    onFieldChange={onFieldChange}
  /> 
);
```

Each input can then invoke `onFieldChange` with the field name and value without concerning itself with the rest of the state:

```
function MyFormComponent ({onFieldChange}) {

  const handler = ({target: {name, value}}) => onFieldChange(name, value);

  return (
    <div>
      <input name="title" value={formState.title} onChange={handler} />
      <input name="bio" value={formState.bio} onChange={handler} />
      <input name="expertise" value={formState.expertise} onChange={handler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you, that should cut about 40 lines minimum out for me.

Comment: Great. I added some suggestions about moving the state merging up. See updated answer.

Comment: Even better, nice solution.